# Website contact form to Asana Api

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am interested to allow my website to send a webform data to an asana project, its for collecting responses from potential clients.

I am unsure the best way to do this, since by using the form, I do not want that the user is required to login, or signup, or anything such as that, the form submission should be anonymous, it should just take whatever is posted and create a task in asana with the text given.

From the documentation, it appears that its always required to login, or connect with asana and this obviously isn't going to work since people are not going to do that in order to send me feedback from the website.

So, is there a way to do this, in the way mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that you need to have an Asana account to make API calls as a particular user. However since you want the submissions to be anonymous *anyway*, there's a pretty simple way: you can create a bot account and use that to submit the form. For instance, create an Asana user called "forms_bot@yourdomain.com"; make sure it can see the project in which you want to collect the form submissions. Get its credentials from inside Asana, and use these on your server to make the API calls to Asana to submit the information. In this way you will see the tasks created by "forms_bot@yourdomain.com".

We use this idiom very frequently at Asana for these sorts of flows, and as an added plus it makes it very clear where the information came from in the first place (as opposed to seeming as if there were an actual user in your domain that's creating the tasks). Hopefully this makes sense and will allow you to get the workflow you want set up!

Comment: Well, as the writer of the website, I dont mind if I have an asana account since then I can use my credentials to create the code necessary to write into the project I want to target.  But I dont want visitors at my site to need an asana account, since that would put an unnecessary blockade for them to create an account first.  If you see what I mean?

Comment: However, thats a really good idea about the asana user, I didnt think about that way, thanks, I will try it out!